How to add processing times to WooCommerce products
I have been using this code snippet for my website products and it works nicely.
Although I want to change the style it already has to something like in the image below. The icons should be in a black circle background with horizontal line in between icons.
I tried to change the angle-double-right FAS icon to horizontal line but it does not display it. How can I change the style as in the picture?
/* Estimated delivery dates widget */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'delivery_status_widget', 40 );
function delivery_status_widget() {
    global $product;
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-P9vJUXK+LyvAzj8otTOKzdfF1F3UYVl13+F8Fof8/2QNb8Twd6Vb+VD52I7+87tex9UXxnzPgWA3rH96RExA7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/solid.min.css" integrity="sha512-tk4nGrLxft4l30r9ETuejLU0a3d7LwMzj0eXjzc16JQj+5U1IeVoCuGLObRDc3+eQMUcEQY1RIDPGvuA7SNQ2w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css">
    <style>
    .delivery-status-widget {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 13px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 14px 10px;
        color: #121212;
        background-color: white;
       /* border: 1px dotted black;*/
        /*color: #121212;*/
       /* border-radius: 6px;*/
    }
    .delivery-status-widget .status {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 15px;
    }
    .delivery-status-widget .status-icon {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #121212!important;
    }
    .delivery-status-widget .status-text {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .delivery-status-widget .status-date {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: gray;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="delivery-status-widget">
        <div class="status">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag status-icon" style="color: 
    gray;"></i>
            <div class="status-text">Ordered</div>
            <div class="status-date" id="order-date"></div>
        </div>
        
    <div class="status">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="status">
            <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast status-icon" style="color: 
    grey;"></i>
            <div class="status-text">Shipped</div>
            <div class="status-date" id="ship-date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
            <i class="fas fa-box-open status-icon" style="color: 
    grey;"></i>
            <div class="status-text">Delivered</div>
            <div class="status-date" id="delivery-date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        // Get the product "shipping""custom fields values"
        $shipval = $product->get_meta('_shipping_days');
        $delival = $product->get_meta('_delivery_days'); 
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var today       = new Date(),
            shipVal     = <?php echo $shipval ? intval( $shipval ) : 3; ?>, // (Default value is "2")
            deliVal     = <?php echo $delival ? intval( $delival ) : 6; ?>; // (Default value is "6")

        // Ordered
        var orderedDate = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
        $("#order-date").text(orderedDate);

        // Shipped
        var shipDate = new Date(today);
        shipDate.setDate(today.getDate() + shipVal);
        shipDate = shipDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
        $("#ship-date").text(shipDate);

        // Delivered
        var deliveryDate = new Date(today);
        deliveryDate.setDate(today.getDate() + deliVal);
        deliveryDate = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
        $("#delivery-date").text(deliveryDate);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_shipping_custom_fields' );
function add_shipping_custom_fields() {
    
    echo '<div class="options_group product_shipping_custom_fields">';
    
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_shipping_days',
            'label'       => 'Shipping Days',
            'desc_tip'    => true,
            'description' => 'Enter the number of days required for shipping',
        )
    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_delivery_days',
            'label'       => 'Delivery Days',
            'desc_tip'    => true,
            'description' => 'Enter the number of days required for delivery',
        )
    );
    
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_shipping_custom_fields' );
function save_shipping_custom_fields( $product ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['_shipping_days']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_shipping_days', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_shipping_days'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['_delivery_days']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_delivery_days', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_delivery_days'] ) );
    }
}

